# Which dictionary view in SAP HANA is equivalent to Oracle v$transaction?

Tags: hana

Do you know which dictionary view in SAP HANA is equivalent to Oracle v$transaction?

As you might know, we can check how much time is used for the individual transaction in Oracle by viewing v$transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here would be on [M_TRANSACTIONS](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/c9610c75191014b01e946bef18c0a7/content.htm%20*SAP%20HANA%20Documentation%20M_TRANSACTIONS*) system view.

Comment: Agree with that. Thank you!